# Not redirecting to other webpage after executing Django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have a view - user types some data in input (in scraping.html), data is subjected to action and score should be displayed on next webpage (scrapingscore.html).

My problem is that after clicking submit button, website 'scraping' is refreshing and nothing happens, only input with textfield disappears.

my view:

```
def scraping(request):
    rootlink = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl'
    link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query='
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("textfield")
        if data is None:
            empty = 'Data is empty'
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'empty':empty})
        else:
            data = data.replace(" ", "+")

            search = link + data + '&x=0&y=0'
            req = Request(
                    search,
                    data=None,
                    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
                    }
                )

            req = urlopen(req).read()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(
                                req,
                                features="lxml"
                                )

            anchor = soup.find("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
            link = anchor.get("href")
            original_link = rootlink + link
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'original_link':original_link})
    return render(request, 'scraping.html')
```

scraping.html

```
<form action="{% url 'scraping' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="text" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

my url to scraping, i don't have url to scrapingscore, maybe should i have with this view?

```
path('scraping', views.scraping, name='scraping'),
```

I don't know how to solve this problem - now 'scrapingscore' webpage does not appear.

Comment: You wrote `data = request.POST.get("textfield")` but in your `scraping.html` there are no any `field` with name `textfield`. I think it should be `data = request.POST.get("text")`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, it looks like it solved part of my problems, now data is displaying :) The only problem is that it is still showing on webpage 'scraping', not in second 'scrapingscore' - i don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form action="/scraping/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="text" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

in your views.py

```
def scraping(request):
    rootlink = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl'
    link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query='
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("textfield")
        if data is None:
            empty = 'Data is empty'
            return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'empty':empty})
        else:
            data = data.replace(" ", "+")

            search = link + data + '&x=0&y=0'
            req = Request(
                    search,
                    data=None,
                    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
                    }
                )

            req = urlopen(req).read()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(
                                req,
                                features="lxml"
                                )

            anchor = soup.find("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
            link = anchor.get("href")
            original_link = rootlink + link
            return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'original_link':original_link})
```

Comment: It still does not change webpage address after clicking 'submit' button, just 'scraping' webpage is refreshing and input disappears

Comment: have you try to change your TemplateResponse to render?

Comment: Yes i tried with render but it didn't change anything. That's why i don't know why it is not redirecting to new webpage.

Comment: I see you changed in view 'TemplateResponse' to 'render', i did it before but it still didn't help :(